# How to draw axes with arrows for X and Y in plotly

Tags: math, graph, plotly

Which seams a basic operation, I couldn't find it docs. Even searching for Google images doesn't show a single example of a chart with typical school-like axes.

How to draw X Y axes with arrows which pass the 0 point? Just like a basic chart known from school blackboards, ideally with ticks, function name, it's formula in LateX etc. Just the basics of a function graph.

My current workaround which gives me lines axes:

```py
X = np.linspace(-10, 10, 2000)
Y = [f(P, x) for x in X]


fig = px.line(x=X, y=Y, range_y=[-50, 50], range_x=[-5, 5])
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, xaxis_title='', yaxis_title='')
fig.add_vline(0)
fig.add_hline(0)
fig.show()
```

Example from wikipedia (sadly without arrows) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function):
[image]

Another example (has arrows, but ugly and no ticks):
[image]

My hand-drawn example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your wishes and created a code with a graph that depicts a general curve, not the curve in your question. The function annotations follow your question.
There seems to be no way to bring the xy axis to the center at this time. Create a new annotation and update the graph.

- Customize graph size to square.
- Hide xy-axis ticks. Set xy-axis to zero point and set axis titles.
- Create new xy-axis ticks manually and in dictionary format.
- Create a new xy-axis arrow manually in dictionary format.
- Combine the dictionaries and set them as annotations.
- Add function formulas as annotations.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

t = np.linspace(-5.0, 5.0, 1000)
s = t**3

fig = px.line(x=t, y=s)

fig.update_layout(autosize=True,
                  width=600,
                  height=600,
                  template=None,
                  showlegend=False,
                  xaxis_title='',
                  yaxis_title='',
                  xaxis=dict(showticklabels=False),
                  yaxis=dict(showticklabels=False)
                 )

fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(zeroline=True,
                             zerolinecolor='black',
                             title_text="X",
                            ))

fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(zeroline=True,
                             zerolinecolor='black',
                             title_text="Y",
                            ))

xaxes_dict = [dict(x=x, y=-7, xref="x", yref="y", text=str(x), showarrow=False) for x in np.arange(-4, 5, 2)]
yaxes_dict = [dict(x=-0.5, y=y, xref="x", yref="y", text=str(y), showarrow=False) for y in np.arange(-100, 101, 50)]

arrowx_dict = [dict(x=0, y=140, ax=0, ay=20, showarrow=True, xref='x', yref='y', arrowhead=5, arrowsize=1.5, arrowwidth=1)]
arrowy_dict = [dict(x=5, y=0, ax=-20, ay=0, showarrow=True, xref='x', yref='y', arrowhead=5, arrowsize=1.5, arrowwidth=1)]

fig.update_layout(annotations=xaxes_dict+yaxes_dict+arrowx_dict+arrowy_dict)

fig.add_annotation(x=0.5, y=50,
                   xref='x',
                   yref='y',
                   text=r'$f(x)=\frac{x^3+3x^2-6x-8}{4}$',
                   font=dict(size=16),
                   showarrow=False,
                   yshift=10)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looks good. However seeing how much coding is required and that it's still not perfect (no ticks, misplaced arrows, overlapping labels, fixed graph size etc), it seems that I should rather adapt plotly standards instead of trying to force it to a format known from math books.

Comment: As explained in the comments, plotly does not have the ability to move axes, so you need to create your own ticks, just as you created your own tick labels. The graph size is automatically horizontal. If you are fine with that, you can disable width and height. What does the overlap of the labels refer to? The misaligned arrows may be feasible if you change the coordinate reference.